# Loopback converting decimals to scientific notation object

Tags: javascript, express, loopbackjs

On my loopback server, I have a calculation for when I do `console.info` it returns:

```
7906.748057713651
```

However, when I return this same number in the results for loopback (datatype object), it looks like this:

```
{
  "s": 1,
  "e": 3,
  "c": [
    7,
    9,
    0,
    6,
    7,
    4,
    8,
    0,
    5,
    7,
    7,
    1,
    3,
    6,
    5,
    1
  ]
}
```

It took me a little while to realize it, but I've finally realized this is scientific notation:

```
c * (s*10) ^ e,7.9067408057713651 * (1 * 10) ^ 3
```

Any thoughts on why it's doing this?

Comment: Use data type string. You define it object so the whole object transmitted

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani I can see how changing the datatype to a string would help, but why is Loopback doing this? I've not had to deal with this before

Comment: And more importantly, how do I fix it?

Comment: Data transferred in json format. Loopback (nodejs) should be able to deal with data. What you show in your question in json format of the data. When loopback wants to send data object it calls `toJSON` function.

Comment: How about `JSON.stringify()`?